# How to create custom background in Google ChromeCast

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, chromecast

Hey guys I'm working on an application to play audio file using `Google` `Chromecast` for I'm passing the mediaInformation with **TrackName, ArtistName and Artwork** as metadata by taking reference to this [Sample](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-ios)

```
GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation = [[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:@"link to my audio file" 
                                                                     streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeNone
                                                                     contentType:@"video/mp4"
                                                                     metadata:metadata
                                                                     streamDuration:0
                                                                     customData:nil];

//cast video
[_mediaControlChannel loadMedia:mediaInformation autoplay:TRUE playPosition:desiredPosition];
```

Everything is okay. Playing song as well showing the meta data. Problem is it's showing the black background. I want to set some custom background like

1. A custom image in background
2. App Logo
3. App Name
4. User Info (Image and Name), etc

I've searched a lot but got no help. Please help me to get out of this situation.

Also, I want to play and pause the audio when it start or stop playing the song on device.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To style your experience on the TV screen, you need to either use a Styled Receiver or write your own custom receiver; see this [page](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps). For controlling the playback, read our [docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/) or look at our sample [apps](https://github.com/googlecast).

Comment: I'm not able to find full sample of custom receiver for iOS. I got this [Simple Receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Simple-Receiver) app sample but it contain only on html page. How do I link my app with this page? Can you please provide a full sample app for iOS using Custom Receiver. Thanks

Comment: Receivers are independent of the sender's platform, so the same receiver works for iOS, Android or Chrome sender. There are samples that you can look up and if you follow the links that I had provided earlier, you will be able to learn about receivers and also find samples to work with.